# a chemical model for pde

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Consider the initial boundary value problem

$$u_t=a(t)u_{xx},\,\,\,0<x<1,\,\,\,t>0$$
$$-ku_x(0,t)=hu(0,t),\,\,\,t>0$$
$$u(1,t)=u_0,\,\,\,t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x),\,\,\,t>0$$
where $a(t)>0$ is time-dependent thermal diffusivity, $k>0$ constant thermal conductivity and $h>0$ constant heat transfer coefficient.

-I wonder that is there any chemical process that can be modelled by the above equation ?
-Is it possible for a physical process that the thermal diffusivity is time dependent but thermal conductivity and heat transfer coefficient are constant ?

Comment: Cross-posted to Physics, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176673/a-physical-model-for-pde